# Python beginner with class variables

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to define a variable in my view like this:

```
class PostMessageView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    url_redirect = None

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return redirect(self.url_redirect)
```

I know this is not the good way, and there are build-in classes for that, but my problem is *not* here. My problem is about pure Python (I guess). If I make a descendant, I can do it like that, it works:

```
class ContactDetailView(PostMessageView):
    template_name = 'my_home/contact_detail.html'
    url_redirect = 'my_profile_contact_detail'
```

My problem is when I want to change `url_redirect` with a dynamic value, like:

```
class ContactDetailView(PostMessageView):
    template_name = 'my_home/contact_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.url_redirect = self.request.build_absolute_uri(self.request.path)
```

Then I get `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` because, I guess, `self.url_redirect` doesn't overwrite `url_redirect`.

How to do it properly in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) for this:

```
class ContactDetailView(PostMessageView):
    template_name = 'my_home/contact_detail.html'

    @property
    def url_redirect(self):
        return self.request.build_absolute_uri(self.request.path)
```

This `url_redirect` method essentially acts like an attribute of the class. Using the decorator version like this will make it a getter only. You can use `property` as a method instead, if you wanted to make a setter as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `get_context_data()` is not called as it should be called by your `post()` method.

This should work:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.get_context_data()
    return redirect(self.url_redirect)
```

However, `get_context_data()` is supposed to return a dictionary of data to pass to the template, it is not supposed alter the object state.